# DB2 DataSource properties for KeyStore are nowhere to be found

Tags: java, db2, datasource, keystore, hikaricp

I'm using db2 datasource with Hikari and I'm trying to set my keystore location and password using either datasource properties with `addDataSourceProperty` or using query params in the url with `setJdbcUrl`.

I'm trying to do it like that instead of setting the keystore location and password with system properties using `setProperty` which is currently working.

However, when I try to use the properties `db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.sslKeyStoreLocation`, `db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.sslKeyStorePassword`, and `db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.sslKeyStoreType`, the `DB2BaseDataSource` class can't find those fields.

Please help if you can, I've been banging my head on this because apparently it's how I'm supposed to do it.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052075.html#imjcc_r0052075__tblcfgpr2

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021822.html

Comment: What's the output on your db2jcc4.jar you use? `java -cp db2jcc4.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`

Comment: that command isn't working for me but my version for db2jcc4.jar in the pom is 4.21.29 ..... this documentation says "introduced in driver version 4.23" .... is that driver version comparable to the db2jcc4.jar version, which is why the keystore properties wouldn't be showing up for me?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052075.html

Comment: Yoy should try the version 4.23 at least as stated.

Comment: Yea version 4.23.42 worked for me.  For some reason it took me forever to see "introduced in version 4.23 " and realize my version wasn't compatible.  You sniffed it out right away which makes sense it's wrong version since the property wasn't available in the class.  If you wanna answer I'll mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following properties are introduced in driver version 4.23 as stated at the link in the question.

```
db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.sslKeyStoreLocation
db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.sslKeyStoreType
db2.jcc.DB2BaseDataSource.sslKeyStorePassword
```